# How to use loops for tasks with intervals?

Tags: javascript, loops, websocket, raspberry-pi

So my use case is that I want to control a stepper motor via a Raspberry Pi. This control should work over a web socket with Socket.io and also does pretty good so far.

Now I want to start turning my motor with one web socket call and also stop it with one single call.

My code so far is this:

```
var looping;
    socket.on('start looping', function() {
        console.log("Start looping");
        var pin = 40;

        rpio.open(pin, rpio.OUTPUT, rpio.LOW);

        looping = setInterval(function(){
            for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
            rpio.write(pin, rpio.HIGH);
            rpio.sleep(0.001);
            rpio.write(pin, rpio.LOW);
        }
        },1);

    });

    socket.on('stop looping', function() {
        console.log("Stop looping");
        clearInterval(looping);
    });
```

As you see I use a `setInterval` with 1 ms interval and inside my loop I switch my pin on and off with a interval of 0.001 seconds.

These two intervals really bother me and I'd like to use one single interval so I am able to control my motor more precisely.

Maybe I am doing this a wrong way. Could you please give me some help or advice how I can solve this more elegant?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Okay... I will reformat my question a little bit:
Before I tried to do my start and stop like so:

```
var running = true

socket.on('start looping', function() {
        console.log("Start looping");
        var pin = 40;

        rpio.open(pin, rpio.OUTPUT, rpio.LOW);

        while(running){
            rpio.write(pin, rpio.HIGH);
            rpio.sleep(0.001);
            rpio.write(pin, rpio.LOW);
        }

socket.on('stop looping', function() {
        console.log("Stop looping");
        running = false
    });
```

But as the `while` loop was preventing to process another socket call I had to use `setInterval`. Maybe this helps in understanding my use case and problem a little bit better.

Comment: Note that setInterval isn't going to wait for asynchronous code inside it. Also it has a minimum delay depending on environment. In browsers for example  I think it is about 4ms regardless of passing it a lower value or no value or zero

Comment: @charlietfl so you're saying my `setInterval` runs every 1ms no matter how long my for loop inside takes to be finished?

This makes my approach even worse in a sense that I do not have a accurate control over my signal in hz and I'm looking for a better way to solve this.